# Parsing with Antlr g4 in RascalMPL

Tags: rascal

Is there a way to parse with g4 grammar in Rascal. I have some grammar written in Antlr how can I use it within rascal with having redefine with rascal. Any resource the illustrates this will also be appreciated

Comment: There are likely a number of things in Antlr that don't have equivalents in Rascal. Lexer rules follow two rules for disambiguation: (1) match the lexer rule with longest string; (2) if two or more lexer rules match, the first wins. Further, Antlr lexers are not parser aware. So, for example, I don't think it's possible in Rascal to do `lexical T1 = [a]+ ; lexical T2 = ([a-z][a-z0-9]*) \ T1;`, but there may be other ways. There may not be equivalents for Antlr lexer commands, or lexer modes.

Comment: Right! The mapping can be compex. Longest match is declarative in Rascal, so you write `[a-z]+ !>> [a-z]` for example. And preference between lexical rules is usually not necessary due to non-deterministic parsing algorithm; usually the parsing context decides which lexical token it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to just type in the grammar again in Rascal. This should be mostly a one to one mapping, but there are usually simplifications to be done to make the Rascal grammar cleaner. For example the operators of expression sublanguages need only one nonterminal name.

An automated migration is possible in principle but the guarantees such a transformation can give are limited. It could accidentally introduce parse errors or ambiguity, or remove errors and ambiguity. This is mostly due to the two stage lexing/parsing setup most people work with in ANTLR, while rascal uses a single stage. Therefore it's much better to understand the mapping manually.

There do exist automated transformations from SDF2 grammars to Rascal, because their semantics is so close.

Comment: What do you mean by "For example the operators of expression sublanguages need only one nonterminal name."?

Comment: That makes sense, Antlr has a very different semantic from Rascal. thanks

Comment: I wish Rascal Syntax definition can be improved upon, or better still isn't it possible to implement a Rascal automated transformation for SDF3?

Comment: @kaby76 in Rascal you would have only `Expression` or `Exp` for all the rules of the expression grammar. So it would look like `syntax Expression = Id | left Expression "*" Expression > left Expression "+" Expression;` for a very simple grammar. Especially for larger grammars like C, Java, C++, COBOL and Ada, which have many dialects, it really helps if you can express the order of the rules and associativity of the rules without restriction. ANTLR has similar constructs but they are not as elegant and simple as this IMHO.

Comment: @PiusArhanbhunde even if we'd add an SDF3 importer, you'd still have to understand what is going on, rule-by-rule. And there are not enough SDF3 grammars for this to make sense yet I think. For ANTLR there is surely a market for it.

Comment: The equivalent of the expression rule implementing operator prec/assoc in Antlr would be `e : Id | e '*' e | e '+' e;`. Antlr disambiguates using alt ordering, grouping, and `<asssoc>`. So, `*` > `+`, left. A few grammars use the "single-rule" syntax (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java) but most do not (c, cpp, cobol/\*, ada/\*) because people entered the grammar from a spec, which usually implements prec/assoc using multiple rules. There is a long-term goal to automate the refactoring of "multi-rule" precedence into a "single-rule" implementation.

Comment: @jurgen Yeah, that does make sense

Comment: @kaby76 there are nice papers about that kind of grammar manipulations by Ralf Lämmel and Vadim Zaytsev (grammarware) and friends; the process of "deyaccification" is a good search term.

Comment: @JurgenVinju Thanks for the info. I have seen Zaytsev's GrammarZoo, and browsed his website https://grammarware.net/ in the past. But, I haven't seen the the transforms he lists in https://slps.github.io/xbgf/ and never heard of "deyaccify". Some of the transformations in XBGF are compositions of others, e.g., "inline" is a "unfold" plus a delete rule. Not sure why it then exists. But, it's all good stuff. We can't deal with grammars by spit-balling changes ad hoc.

Comment: deyaccificaition is described in  R. Lämmel. Grammar Adaptation. In Proceedings of the International Symposium
of Formal Methods Europe on Formal Methods for Increasing Software Productivity,
volume 2021 of LNCS, pages 550–570. Springer, 2001.
23. R. Lämmel and C. Verhoef. Semi-automatic Grammar Recovery. Software—
Practice & Experience, 31(15):1395–1438, December 2001